# Entity Framework Core 3.0 .Select() not mapping Child object

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two table 'Product' and 'UserProductViews', When a user views a product a row is inserted in 'UserProductViews' table with products Id, even if the user views the same product again. My goal is to show recently view products to users.

Original I planned to use .GroupBy() on 'UserProductViews' table but according to my understanding in .Net Core 3.1 we cannot use .GroupBy() directly on dbcontext.UserProductViews as I will need to do IEnumerable() first which is not good for me and cannot use .Distinct() because 'UserProductViews' contains Created Date and Modified Date . However after trying alot of ways I solved it with following query:

```
return _context.UserProductViews.Include(x => x.Product)
             .Include(x => x.Product.ProductTags)
             .Include(x => x.Product.ProductBrand)
             .Include(x => x.Product.ProductAttributes)
             .Include(x => x.Product.ProductMedia)
             .Include(x => x.Product.ProductVariants)
             .ThenInclude(x => x.ProductVariantAttributeValues)
             .Include(x => x.Product.Company)
             .Include(x => x.Product.Country)
             .Include(x => x.Product.ProductClassification)
             .Where(x =>
                x.UserId == userId
                && x.Product.Status == ProductStatus.Active
                && x.Product.ProductType == ProductType.Physical
                && x.Product.ProductMedia.Any())

        .Select(x => new RecentlyViewdProductResponse
        {
            Product = x.Product,
            UserProductViewId = x.UserProductViewId
        }).Distinct()
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.UserProductViewId)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .GetPagedAsync(page, pageSize);


public static async Task<PagedResult<T>> GetPagedAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> query,
                                     int page, int pageSize) where T : class
    {
        var result = new PagedResult<T>();
        result.CurrentPage = page;
        result.PageSize = pageSize;
        result.RowCount = query.Count();


        var pageCount = (double)result.RowCount / pageSize;
        result.PageCount = (int)Math.Ceiling(pageCount);

        var skip = (page - 1) * pageSize;
        result.Results = await query.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();

        return result;
    }
```

I am getting all 'userProductViews' and selecting 'product' child object of userProductViews (selecting product so I can use .Distinct() on the product) with userProductViews's Id (just to order by its Id)

The Problem here is if I use .Select() and map the userProductViews.product to product (they are the same class), than product's inner child object doesn't map with it. As you see in the image:
[With select query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzsJc.png)

But if I remove .Select() and get complete 'userProductViews' and go to its child 'product' I can see that they are than included in it: [Without select query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgolG.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution. It is best what I can imagine with EF Core without raw SQL.

```cs
var latest = 
    from pv in _context.UserProductViews
    where pv.UserId == userId
        && pv.Product.Status == ProductStatus.Active
        && pv.Product.ProductType == ProductType.Physical
        && pv.Product.ProductMedia.Any()
    group pv by pv.ProductId into g
    select new 
    {
        ProductId = g.Key,
        UserProductViewId = g.Max(x => x.UserProductViewId)
    }

var productViews = _context.UserProductViews
    .Include(x => x.Product)
    .Include(x => x.Product.ProductTags)
    .Include(x => x.Product.ProductBrand)
    .Include(x => x.Product.ProductAttributes)
    .Include(x => x.Product.ProductMedia)
    .Include(x => x.Product.ProductVariants)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.ProductVariantAttributeValues)
    .Include(x => x.Product.Company)
    .Include(x => x.Product.Country)
    .Include(x => x.Product.ProductClassification));

var query = 
    from pv in productViews
    join q in latest on pv.UserProductViewId equals q.UserProductViewId
    orderby pv.UserProductViewId descending
    select new RecentlyViewdProductResponse
    {
        Product = pv.Product,
        UserProductViewId = pv.UserProductViewId
    };

return await query.GetPagedAsync(page, pageSize);
```

Comment: The result is correct but the problem remains the same. I am unable to get 'product' table inner child objects.

Comment: So, then you have to do custom projection for each related object.